# How to break this cycle?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, cycle, eof

I was writing a program that reads a text and convert quotes, and I have a problem finishing the cycle with condition `hasNext()`, the program should end with EOF, could you please help me?

Here is the cycle I mentioned:

```
  boolean reference= false;     
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        String text = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {
            if(text.charAt(i)=='"' && reference==false)
            {
                reference=true;
                System.out.print("``");
            }
            else if(text.charAt(i)=='"' && reference == true)
            {
                reference=false;
                System.out.print("''");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are reading from a file ?

Comment: It seems you are using Scanner. Scanner class has a method called close() - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard No, I'm just reading what I type on the console.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath Yes, I tried to use it but it didn't work, the thing is that I don't know how to tell the program where is the EOF.

Comment: @SebastianRojasCaballero, how do you know it did not work? Did it keep reading? If that is the case, then you could simply use break;

Answer (score 2):

> @Jean-FrançoisSavard No, I'm just reading what I type on the console.

When reading from the console, the `hasNext()` method will loop until <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (windows) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (unix) is typed.

This is the way to send EOF *(break this cycle)* to `System.in`.

Comment: I didn't know that, but I have to post this code on a website call uva.onliine.judge and there's a machine that reads the whole code and it tells you whether the problem is being solved or not, the machine won't type ctrl+z or ctrl+d to end it, instead, will tell me that the problem has a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `while (input.hasNextLine())` because you read the next Line after.

Comment: Doesn't matter much in this case.